# rails 3 localized user input

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, floating-point

I am developing a web application primarily for the german market. I want my users to be able to input floats the way it is usually in germany, with a comma `float = 1,5`.

Currently I use a pseudo attribute in the model that switches the comma for a fullstop. But there must be a better way. Any ideas?

Example how I currently do it:

```
def localized_float
  vh.number_with_precision(hourly_wage, :precision => 2)
end

def localized_float=(value)
  self[:float] = value.gsub('.', '').gsub(',', '.')
end
```

Thank you for any hints!

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the **gem delocalize** which does exactly what you looking for. https://github.com/clemens/delocalize

Comment: It could be tricky to use the delocalize together with simple_form.

Answer (score 1):

Try the gem https://github.com/carlosantoniodasilva/i18n_alchemy
It seems simpler in scope and better supported than delocalize.